# Did the "unexpectedness" of key events argue against a "third strike" at Pearl Harbor?

Tags: world-war-two, united-states, japan

Japan's Admiral Nagumo has been criticized for not launching a ["third strike"](https://nationalinterest.org/blog/buzz/what-if-imperial-japan-had-launched-third-wave-attack-against-pearl-harbor-126742) at Pearl Harbor, specifically to destroy the dry docks, fuel stores, repair facilities and other key infrastructure. The argument in favor of third strike is that it would have set back the American pacific war effort by a year or more, say until mid to late 1943. Weighed against this was the likelihood of heavier bomber losses that would be inflicted by now fully-alerted American defenses, and the chance that the "missing" American carriers would unexpectedly return and sink one or more Japanese carriers either outside Pearl Harbor, or on their way home (and low on fuel).

Sources like [this American naval history](https://www.history.navy.mil/content/dam/nhhc/research/histories/naval-aviation/USNavalAviationInthePacific/pacific.pdf) argue that without the humongous (and totally unexpected) American victory at [Midway,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Midway) and the early shift in the balance of naval power, the American Pacific offensive would not have started until year after it did; that is summer/fall 1943, instead of the summer of 1942 (at Guadalcanal). That is, only the unforeseeable success at Midway made the Pearl Harbor infrastructure the critical time factor for the resurgence in American pacific activity. Presumably, the Japanese thought much the same thing.

If one were working on the assumption the Pearl Harbor infrastructure was NOT the critical time-determining factor, how would that affect the calculations about whether or not to launch a "third strike?"

Answer (score 7):

**Short Answer:**

1/ Events six months after Pearl Harbour strike were too uncertain to be considered

2/ The American offensive from the base of Pearl Harbour did not start in summer 1942 at Guadalcanal, but at the Marshall islands in 1943

**Long Answer**

I think there are a few misconceptions in the question that should be clarified:

First, the third strike at Pearl Harbourcould have targeted drydocks and other infrastructures, but it could not have been hard enough to destroy them massively. Japanese bombers involved were "only" small one, because they were carrier-based, and the amount of explosives carried was relatively small because of that.

Second, the plan to attack Midway had not been elaborate at the time of Pearl Harbour: as a consequence, the Japanese did not imagine that there would be such a gap in the center Pacific at fall 1942.

Third, after the battle of Midway, the Americans started to consider offensive but they did not launch the offensive: the battle of Guadalcanal began only as a preemptive attack in the Solomons archipelago, and not as a big push. The Japanese reaction transformed it in a big battle.
Neither did the Americans thought about an offensive in the Center Pacific before 1943.

So overall, the consideration that a "Midway-type" defeat happened or not did not influence the Japanese at Pearl Harbour: this was too far in the future, and they were more concerned about the need for their carriers to remain to lead the attack in the South-West Pacific.

Comment: OK, I forgot an important consideration. A hypothetical Japanese "third strike" against Pearl Harbor would likely have caused only "partial," not "full" damage to the infrastructure.

Comment: Actually even partial damage could be important for later American consolidation

Comment: ***Actually***: crippling losses among the Japanese aircrew of a third wave, from an alerted and angry American defense, would have ended Japanese imperial ambitions almost as effectively as midway did. A bugaboo for the Japanese , right from the beginning of the war, was an inability to replace air crew as they had no infrastructure in place for large scale training - and no fuel available to provide training hours.

Comment: How much importance did the infrastructure actually have?  My impression is that the Pacific war was almost entirely based on mainland production.

Comment: @jamesqf: I don't think Hawaii was noted for its "production." More like a "forward base," several time zones into the Pacific Ocean, for repair and resupply. It would likely make a difference whether this could take place in Hawaii or California.

Comment: Plenty of (more heavily damaged) ships were sent to west coast ports for repairs. Hawaii handled a bunch of quick repairs, but not major overhauls. That was the job of Bremerton, San Diego, etc.

Comment: @Tom Au: I was thinking more along the lines of value of repaired ships, vs value of newly-built ones.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens True, but would such crippling losses actually happen? I think more about the American defenses being able to disturb proper Japanese bombing, thus reducing the actual effect of the third wave

Comment: @totalMongot: Japan lost 9 planes in the first wave, and another 20 in the second. Additionally, planes returning from a third wave would have had to land at night - for which the Japanese had no training or experience. It's not inconceivable that a Japanese [third wave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attack_on_Pearl_Harbor#American_casualties_and_damage) would have lost 40 or more planes over Hawaii; and a dozen or 3 in night landings, given their inexperience. Additionally, it would have consumed the very last fuel reserve for the home-bound fleet.

Comment: I am not sure about the Japanese having no training for night landing. Anyway, 40 planes lost and safe carriers could not be compared to the losses of Midway

Comment: @totalMongo: A night landing is not at all the same as a night landing on a carrier.  Much more difficult - and you first have to find the carrier in the dark before you can land on it.

Comment: @jamesqf the dry dock and other facilities at Pearl were vital to the war effort in that they reduced the turnaround time for repairs and replenishment of combat units by weeks. Without those dry docks especially most of the ships that were recovered from damage in the strike against Pearl would have to have been scuttled rather than repaired, setting back the US war effort by months at the very least all on its own, giving the Japanese the breathing room they now didn't get enough of to launch their invasion of Australia.

Comment: @jwenting I agree with the overall point about facilities, but not for the specific application you gave: the battle of Coral sea was led by ships that were not damaged at Pearl Harbour. For them, Pearl Harbour served as a supply base and not a drydock

Comment: @jamesqf, Admiral Nimitz estimated that the loss of the fuel tanks at Pearl Harbor would have delayed large-scale American operations in the Pacific by at least a year.

Comment: @totalMongot think further ahead. The ships that were damaged at Pearl and repaired eventually rejoined the fleet in late 1942/early 1943. Had they remained at the bottom not only would the Pearl be out of the fight for the duration, but those US fleet strength wouldn't have been up to pre-war levels until later than it was now.

Comment: @jwenting I agree for 1943, but you said "giving the Japanese the breathing room they now didn't get enough of to launch their invasion of Australia" so it was specific reference to the battle of Coral sea, thus I reacted. But now that you changed the scope, I agree :)